# How to connect UIButton and a method programmatically?

Tags: objective-c

In my `UIView`, i have a `UIButton` displayed.

Inside same UIView class i have a method i'd like to be executed when button is pressed.

When **everything is done programmatically, without the use of Interface Builder**, how can one link the two together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvents: message to specify a selector for the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIControl addTarget: forControlEvents: